# How to query the column description of a table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there any query to get the list of columns with its primarykey foreign key reference?

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, CHARacter_maximum_length
FROM DBTIME.information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'Table Name'
```

From this query I am getting the datatype and maximum length of a column. Along with this I need to know its foreign key primary key reference. Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    K_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME,
    FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME,
    PK_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME,
    PK_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME,
    Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK
    ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK
    ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU
    ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        i1.TABLE_NAME,
        i2.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2
        ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
) PT
    ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: i split the last portion to get the exact result PT.TABLE_NAME = 'Company' and PK.TABLE_NAME = 'Company'...Thank you...:)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'Table Name' 
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where TABLE_NAME='Table Name'// It will list all the primary key and foreign key references.
```

Comment: is there any query to get the keytype of a column alone. i mean, i need to know whether the column is a primary key or a foreign key.if a foreign key,then to which field of which table. Is that possible to find from one query?